# How to inform users for update of android app

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps

Yesterday I've updated my android app in google play. Is there any way to "broadcast" some information to android market users that this app is updated?

I have some of the apps on my android phone that from time to time they tries to update themselves, so I was wondering if this is some Google Play trick or this should be build in the app itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do anything to let your users know about the app update. If they have the notifications on for your app (which by default is on), they will automatically be notified about the update whenever it is available and they have access to internet.

Comment: `All you need to do is change your version code and version name so that they know the app is updated,.` - you are not able to post new APK to Play Store without that anyway

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski That's right. Thanks for mentioning that